# Discord not printing the custom emoji on the embed?

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to use a custom emoji `<:pepeheart:717024174882947122>`, that I have on my server into one of the embeds I'm trying to post in the introduction channel. But instead of the bot print the emoji it simply prints the name of it like this `:pepeheart:`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the custom emoji using it's ID before using it, in this case its `717024174882947122`

```js
const pepeHeartEmoji = client.emojis.cache.get('717024174882947122')
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setDescription(`${pepeHeartEmoji} Hello! ${pepeHeartEmoji}`)
```

Comment: i''ve only got one problem which is i'm using a code block (```) and using ` won't work

Comment: You can't use emojis in code blocks so why are you sending it in a code block?

Comment: yes sir, but took a bit for the bot to actually do it